# How do I input text automatically with python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, chromium

I know these method `element.send_keys('txt')` and `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', 'txt')", email)`.

I tried both of them.
But, I couldn't input the text. I think that following site controls input by javascript.
https://login.account.rakuten.com/sso/authorize?client_id=affiliate_jp_web&redirect_uri=https://affiliate.rakuten.co.jp/auth/callback&response_type=code&scope=openid&ui_locales=ja-JP&state=https%3A%2F%2Faffiliate.rakuten.co.jp#/sign_in

In this case, is it possible to input the text in any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can do through `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@name='username']').send_keys('test')`

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I could too. In my case, `driver.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='username']")))` seemed not to work..

Comment: @naohide_a but your question was you were not able to input text

Comment: Yes. After getting element, I did `send_keys`. I mean that I didn't get the element right.